# Regex: Select multiple lines between characters

Tags: php, regex

I can't select multiple lines between two characters on regex.
how can i solve this?

```
{
example
example 1
}
```

I want to select 'example'. but i cant.

I tried this regex

```
#\n.*#
```

thank you

Comment: The literal pattern `#\n.*#`? That's ... not going to do what you want at all, given the example here. In this case, I suspect you're lacking `\r` before `\n`, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your pattern does not do what you expect; it matches a newline character followed by any character except newline "zero or more" times. You need to use the `s` (*dotall*) modifier which forces the dot to match across newline sequences.

For example — matching everything between the two curly braces.

```
preg_match('/{(.*)}/s', $str, $match);
echo $match[1];
```

Comment: To just grab "example", `{\s*([^\n]+)`